# Is it possible to get the Magento indexer to display % complete?

Tags: indexing, cli, command-line

Right now you are left wondering what is going on during indexing, especially on large catalogs where it takes hours to complete just one index.

Is there an easy way to get the command line `indexer.php` to display a percent complete when re-indexing the store indexes?

Comment: if you install mytop, it will be more informative than looking at percentage spinner :)

Comment: Actually, this is "possible". On one hackathon a team built this: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_IndexerStats they measure the time of an indexing and use this to show a status bar. It is not really the status, but gives a feeling.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I was looking for command line, but that works for me! Please post this as an official answer when this gets reopened and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the indexers are, that most of the stuff is running on MySQL level, therefore you can't just hook somewhere in PHP and give an estimation.

Some colleagues built on a hackathon a module which measures the time the indexer is running and built upon this an estimation for the next time, you can checkout it here:

[Hackathon_IndexerStats](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_IndexerStats)